# How do I make the code return the text using xpath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, xpath

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import time


#Gets prices
page = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=hi')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
price = tree.xpath('//h2[@data-attribute="Hi Guess the Food - What’s the Food Brand in the Picture"]/text()')

print(price)
```

This only returns []

When looking into page.content, it shows the amazon anti bot stuff. How can I bypass this?

Comment: Well, have you looked into `page.content`?

Answer (score 0):

One general advice when you're trying to scrap something from some website. Take a look first to the returned content, in this case `page.content` before trying anything. You're assuming wrongly amazon is allowing you nicely to fetch their data, when they don't.

Answer (score 0):

I think urllib2 is better, and xpath could be:

```
price = c.xpath('//div[@class="s-item-container"]//h2')[0]
print price.text
```

After all, long string may contains strange characters.